# How to update total price when an item is dropped?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag items onto a purchase basket. Once the item is dropped into the basket, the items price will be updated into the total price of the basket. Am I missing something? It allows me to drop onto "cart" but does not update the total price.

```
$(".item").draggable({
    revert : true
});
$("#i1").draggable();
$("#i2").draggable();
$("#i3").draggable();
$("#cart").droppable({
    drop : function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".price");
        total_price = total_price + price;
        $("#cprice").html("$ " + total_price);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think we gonna need html or something else...

Answer (score 0):

Where are `total_price` and `price` variables defined?

Try this.

```
var total_price = 0;//Declare and initialize the variable to 0

$("#cart").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    //Add the dragged item's price to total_price and update the cart price
    total_price = total_price + parseFloat($(this).find(".price").text());
    $("#cprice").html("$ " + total_price);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I replaced the line in my drop function, ,and it updated the total price. Unfortunately, the total price displayed "NaN". What does that mean?

Comment: That means `Not a Number`. Can check  my edited answer, I hope it is fixed now.

Comment: It is returning "NaN" because the first number in ".price" is "$". Is there anything else I could use to read in the ".price"?

Comment: Sorry, dumb question. I fixed it.